# Rows sequence by group using two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, seq, cumsum, rle

Suppose I have the following df

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
               Value = c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0),
               Result = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1,2,2,3,1,1,1))
```

How can I obtain column *Result* from the first two columns?

I have tried different approaches using rle, seq, cumsum and cur_group_id but can't get the *Result* column easily

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by obtaining the result column. What calculation are you trying to do to achieve the `Result` column?

Comment: @KentOrr Have a look at the answers, I was trying to create an identifier for each combination of ID and value. The identifier must be the same for both ID and value, and increase when the value of 'Value' column changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Result2 = rleid(Value))
```

This gives us:

```
     ID Value Result Result2
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <int>
 1     1     1      1       1
 2     1     1      1       1
 3     1     0      2       2
 4     1     1      3       3
 5     1     0      4       4
 6     1     1      5       5
 7     1     1      5       5
 8     2     1      1       1
 9     2     0      2       2
10     2     0      2       2
11     2     1      3       3
12     3     0      1       1
13     3     0      1       1
14     3     0      1       1
```

Comment: That was fast, elegant and direct. Thank you

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(r = rep(seq_along(rle(ID*Value)$values), rle(ID*Value)$lengths))
# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID Value Result     r
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
 1     1     1      1     1
 2     1     1      1     1
 3     1     0      2     2
 4     1     1      3     3
 5     1     0      4     4
 6     1     1      5     5
 7     1     1      5     5
 8     2     1      1     1
 9     2     0      2     2
10     2     0      2     2
11     2     1      3     3
12     3     0      1     1
13     3     0      1     1
14     3     0      1     1
```

Comment: Thank you, for your dplyr only based response. I was trying to do something similar with seq_along and rle but failed

Answer (score 1):

We could use `rle` with `ave` in `base R`

```
data$Result2 <- with(data, ave(Value, ID, FUN = 
   function(x) inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x), values <- seq_along(values)))))
data$Result2
#[1] 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 1 2 2 3 1 1 1
```